# How to prevent parameter binding from interpreting commas in Spring 3.0.5?

Tags: java, spring, data-binding, spring-mvc

Consider the following controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void test(@RequestParam(value = "fq", required = false) String[] filterQuery) {
    logger.debug(fq = " + StringUtils.join(filterQuery, "|"));
}
```

Here is the output for different `fq` combinations:

1. `/test?fq=foo` results in `fq = foo`
2. `/test?fq=foo&fq=bar` results in `fq = foo|bar`
3. `/test?fq=foo,bar` results in `fq = foo|bar`
4. `/test?fq=foo,bar&fq=bash` results in `fq = foo,bar|bash`
5. `/test?fq=foo,bar&fq=` results in `fq = foo,bar|`

Example 3 is the problem. I expect (want/need) it to output `fq = foo,bar`.

I've tried escaping the comma with `\` and using `%3C` but niether work.

If I look at the `HttpServletRequest` object's version:

```
String[] fqs = request.getParameterValues("fq");
logger.debug(fqs = " + StringUtils.join(fqs, "|"));
```

It prints the expected output: `fqs = foo,bar`. So the "problem" is with the Spring data binding.

I could by-pass Spring's binding and use `HttpServletRequest` but I really don't want to as I'm using a **backing bean** in my real code (same thing is happening) and don't wish to re-implement the binding functionality. I'm hoping someone can provide a simple way of preventing this behavior via escaping or some other mechanism.

TIA

**UPDATE:** I posted this Q on Twitter and got a reply saying **the expected output appears with Spring 3.0.4.RELEASE**. I've now confirmed this is the case and thus is a temporary fix. I'll go ahead and log this as a bug on the Spring JIRA system. If anyone can provide a work around or fix with 3.0.5, I'll accept their answer.

Comment: Logged as bug: http://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-7963

Comment: I suggest you add your resolution as an answer to your own question to make it clearer to others that you have found a solution.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Phillip. It turns out that the fix of using 3.0.4 works for @RequestMapping but does NOT fix the same issue when binding to a form-backing bean. So I've not got a fix for my application yet. I've still not got a comment/update on the Spring Jira issue yet - which is a bit slack of them I think.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I've tested your code: it's unbelievable, but I can't reproduce your issue. I've downloaded the latest version of spring (3.0.5), this is my controller:

```
package test;

import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/test/**")
public class MyController {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyController.class);

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test/params", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void test(SearchRequestParams requestParams, BindingResult result) {
    logger.debug("fq = " + StringUtils.join(requestParams.getFq(), "|"));
    }
}
```

this is my SearchRequestParams class:

```
package test;

public class SearchRequestParams {
    private String[] fq;

    public String[] getFq() {
    return fq;
    }

    public void setFq(String[] fq) {
    this.fq = fq;
    }
}
```

and this is my simple spring configuration:

```
<bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />

<bean class="test.MyController" />

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I've tested my code within tomcat 7.0.8; when I type `http://localhost:8080/testweb/test/params.htm?fq=foo,bar` I'm able to read in my log file this line: `DEBUG fq = foo,bar`.
What are the the differences from my code to yours? Am I doing something wrong?
I'd like to help you, so if you have any doubts or if I can do some other tests for you, it will be a pleasure.

**UPDATE / SOLUTION**
With your code I've reproduced the issue; you have the tag `<mvc:annotation-driven />` in your dispatcher servlet configuration, so you silently use a default conversion service, instance of `FormattingConversionService`, which contains a default converter from `String` to `String[]` that uses comma as separator.
You have to use a different conversion service bean containing your own converter from `String` to `String[]`. You should use a different separator, I've choosed to use ";" because it's the separator commonly used into query string ("?first=1;second=2;third=3"):

```
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;

public class CustomStringToArrayConverter implements Converter<String, String[]>{
   @Override
    public String[] convert(String source) {
        return StringUtils.delimitedListToStringArray(source, ";");
    }
}
```

Then you have to specify this conversion service bean in your configuration:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="conversionService" />

<bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean">
    <property name="converters">
        <list>
            <bean class="au.org.ala.testspringbinding.CustomStringToArrayConverter" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The issue has fixed, now you should check for any side effects. I hope you don't need in your application the original conversion from `String` to `String[]` (with comma as separator). ;-)

Comment: Thanks for that. The code you pasted is basically what I'm using. I've still got the controller method in my webapp and I just tried it again and still see the "foo|bar" in my version. I'm now wondering if I'm getting one of those strange maven dependency problems as I have a dependency on a project that uses an older version of Spring. I'll make a brand new "bare" Spring project and try it out and report back.

Comment: I just created a new Maven webapp (JEE 6) with Spring MVC 3.0.5 support (using Netbeans). I modified the pom a bit and created two classes as per this answer. Ran the webapp in both Jetty and tomcat (6.0.20) and I still get the output fq = foo|bar (I have the output going to the browser now). I've put the code up on Google Code here: svn checkout http://ala-hubs.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/testSpringBinding - would love to get to the bottom of this...

Comment: Well, I'm glad to help you, let me see your code. I will post some news in a few hours.

Comment: Awesome research and work - this answer didn't fit my project exactly but I do have to say the question and answer are great.

Comment: What's the Java code equivalent to the XML you've posted?

Answer (score 34):

I have found the most elegant and the shortest way for me - add `@InitBinder` to a `@Controller`:

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.registerCustomEditor(String[].class, new StringArrayPropertyEditor(null));
}
```

It will convert String to String[] without using separator (`null` param), with Spring class org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.StringArrayPropertyEditor.
If someone in same project will use new default conversion way, it will be ok.

Comment: Easy implementation, perfect solution to my code - thanks!

Comment: Works in Spring 4 as well.  However, if declaring params as List<String> rather than String[], it won't work, even when using List as the class.  I didn't have the time to dig into Spring internals to find out why and just changed to using String[] for my parameters rather than List<String>.

Comment: It's not clear from the JavaDoc, but using `null` as separator param doesn't seem to be supported. It's better to use a actual character other than a comma.

Comment: This workaround also worked for me with @RestController in spring boot version 1.5.19

Comment: Best answer for me.
@beaudet, it is StringArrayPropertyEditor, so naturally it won't work for lists. Try  `binder.registerCustomEditor(List.class, new CustomCollectionEditor(List.class));`

Answer (score 8):

rougou's comment was the only solution that worked for me because I was using `List<String>` instead of `String[]`.

Add this to your controller to eliminate parsing comma-deliminated values:

```
    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.registerCustomEditor(List.class, new CustomCollectionEditor(List.class));
    }
```

Comment: This solution is working for me with List

Answer (score 4):

As suggested by Philip Potter, I'm posting the "update" to my question as an answer, as it might've been easy to miss...

Down-grading from Spring 3.0.5.RELEASE to 3.0.4.RELEASE **fixed** the issue, when using the `@RequestParam` annotation, suggesting it is a bug with 3.0.5.

However, it does NOT fix the **related issue**, when binding to a form-backing bean - which is what I have in my webapp. I've tested all version back to 3.0.0.RELEASE and get the same result (`/test?fq=foo,bar` produces `fq = foo|bar`).

E.g.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void test(SearchRequestParams requestParams, BindingResult result) {
    logger.debug("fq = " + StringUtils.join(requestParams.getFq(), "|"));
}
```

where `SearchRequestParams` contains a field `String[] fq`.

If anyone has a fix for this, I'll gladly accept their answer.

Comment: Update for posterity: Javanna correctly identified the issue in the accepted answer above.

Answer (score 3):

javanna already pointed out the correct root cause. I just wanted to further point out that you can also remove the StringToArrayConverter altogether [as shown here](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-framework-issues/blob/master/SPR-7963/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/servlet-context.xml#L11) and [here](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-framework-issues/blob/master/SPR-7963/src/main/java/org/springframework/issues/TestFormatterRegistrar.java).

Answer (score 1):

The following is my journey of bypassing comma delimiting in a MVC request

This is my understanding of Springs evolution of these type of solutions:
The documentation is very vague about what is the latest solution.

First was WebMvcConfigAdapter implementing the interface WebMvcConfig.  This was eventually deprecated

That was replaced by WebMvcConfigSupport.  This was eventually deprecated but it was better than the first solution.
The main issued was that it turned off the MVC auto-configuration and had side issues like swagger.html not working and
actuator info being missing pretty format and the date became a large decimal

The latest is a revised interface WebMvcConfig that implements default methods using Java 8 features.

Create a class in my case, WebConfigUUID could be AnyClass, that implements the later version of WebMvcConfig

This allows you to change what you need, in our case a custom converter, 
without impacting anything else or having to override another to get swagger to work, 
or deal with actuator info output

The following are the two classes that implemented my change to bypass comma delimiting of strings to a list
in processing the MVC request:
It still produces a list of strings but with only one value.

```
import java.util.Collection;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.format.FormatterRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
@Configuration
public class WebConfigUUID implements WebMvcConfigurer {
  @Override
  public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry)  {
    registry.removeConvertible(String.class,Collection.class);
    registry.addConverter(String.class,Collection.class,BypassCommaDelimiterConfiguration.commaDelimiterBypassedParsingConverter());
  }
}

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;

public class BypassCommaDelimiterConfiguration  {
    public static Converter<String, List<String>> commaDelimiterBypassedParsingConverter() {
        return new Converter<String, List<String>>() {
            @Override
            public List<String> convert(final String source) {
                final List<String> classes = new ArrayList<String>();
                classes.add(source);
                return classes;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: I meant WebMvcConfigurer as represented in the code

Answer (score 0):

Its a hack but, have you considered passing your params delimited with '-'

```
/test?fq=foo-bar results in fq = foo-bar
/test?fq=foo-bar&fq=bash results in fq = foo-bar|bash
```

Or any other delimiter maybe ~, or !,or ^, or ???

Comment: The parameter values come from Solr facets - and although I could munge them at index time to replace the comma with something_else, it is too much extra effort for what is, I agree, a hack.