# Spring REST service: retrieving JSON from Request

Tags: json, spring, rest

I am building a REST service on Spring 3.1. I am using @EnableWebMVC annotation for that. Since my service will only be accepting JSON requests, I would also like to dump the incoming request into a MongoDB collection for logging (and, later, for data transformation). I would like to access the raw JSON Request (which I could do on a non-spring implementation using "@Content HttpServletRequest request" as a method parameter).

I am a Spring newbie. So, kindly help me with directions to achieve this. Thanks!

**UPDATE: The issue is not completely resolved. Only my tests with GET worked. It fails with POST. Therefore unchecked the accepted answer**

The issue is, even if I create a HttpServletRequestWrapper, I cannot forward the request after I process and wrap the request. Here is what happens:

**Interceptor:**

```
public class DBLogInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
    MyRequestWrapper requestWrapper;

    private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DBLogInterceptor.class);

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            Object handler) throws Exception 
    {
        requestWrapper = new MyRequestWrapper(request);
        // Code removed, but it just dumps requestWrapper.getBody() into DB
        return super.preHandle(requestWrapper, response, handler);
    }
}
```

**HTTP POST Servicing method**

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/json", produces="application/json", value = "employee")
@ResponseBody
public String updateEntity(@RequestBody Employee emp) {
    // Do some DB Stuff. Anyway, the control flow does not reach this place.
    return "Employee " + emp.getName() + " updated successfully!";
}
```

Now I get an exception whenever I send a POST:

```
12:04:53,821 DEBUG DBLogInterceptor:22 - {"name":"Van Damme","dept":"Applied Martial Arts"}
12:04:53,843 DEBUG RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor:117 - Reading [com.test.webapp.login.domain.Employee] as "application/json" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter@154174f9]
12:04:53,850 DEBUG ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver:132 - Resolving exception from handler [public java.lang.String com.test.webapp.controller.EmployeeService.updateEntity(com.test.webapp.login.domain.Employee)]: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
12:04:53,854 DEBUG ResponseStatusExceptionResolver:132 - Resolving exception from handler [public java.lang.String com.test.webapp.controller.EmployeeService.updateEntity(com.test.webapp.login.domain.Employee)]: java.io.IOException: Streamclosed
12:04:53,854 DEBUG DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver:132 - Resolving exception from handler [public java.lang.String com.test.webapp.controller.EmployeeService.updateEntity(com.test.webapp.login.domain.Employee)]: java.io.IOException: Streamclosed
12:04:53,859 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:910 - Could not complete request
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:312)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:200)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.ByteSourceBootstrapper.ensureLoaded(ByteSourceBootstrapper.java:507)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.ByteSourceBootstrapper.detectEncoding(ByteSourceBootstrapper.java:129)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.ByteSourceBootstrapper.constructParser(ByteSourceBootstrapper.java:224)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.JsonFactory._createJsonParser(JsonFactory.java:785)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.JsonFactory.createJsonParser(JsonFactory.java:561)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1914)
        at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.readInternal(MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.java:124)
        at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:153)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:120)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:91)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:71)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:75)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:156)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I expected the `HttpServletRequestWrapper` to be taking care of caching the request. But it doesn't happen somehow.

Comment: This is an issue with Jackson rather than with Spring, you can be without Spring and still experience this

Answer (score 35):

Using the [HttpServletRequest](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) object, you can get access to the URL the client used to make the request, the method used (GET, POST, PUT, etc), the query string, and headers.

Getting the RequestBody may be a bit trickier and may require using the [HttpServletRequestWrapper](http://natch3z.blogspot.com/2009/01/read-request-body-in-filter.html) object.  Since the request body can only be read once, you'll need to extend the wrapper to access it so that your target controller can still access it later to deserialize your JSON into POJO objects.

```
public class MyRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {
 private final String body;
 public MyRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
   super(request);
   StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
   BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
   try {
     InputStream inputStream = request.getInputStream();
     if (inputStream != null) {
       bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
       char[] charBuffer = new char[128];
       int bytesRead = -1;
       while ((bytesRead = bufferedReader.read(charBuffer)) > 0) {
         stringBuilder.append(charBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
       }
     } else {
       stringBuilder.append("");
     }
   } catch (IOException ex) {
       throw ex;
   } finally {
     if (bufferedReader != null) {
       try {
         bufferedReader.close();
       } catch (IOException ex) {
         throw ex;
       }
     }
   }
   body = stringBuilder.toString();
 }

 @Override
 public ServletInputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
   final ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new     ByteArrayInputStream(body.getBytes());
   ServletInputStream servletInputStream = new ServletInputStream() {
     public int read() throws IOException {
       return byteArrayInputStream.read();
     }
   };
   return servletInputStream;
 }

 @Override
 public BufferedReader getReader() throws IOException {
   return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.getInputStream()));
 }

 public String getBody() {
   return this.body;
 }
}
```

To access the requests in a central location, you can use either a Filter or a Spring Interceptor. Both of these are invoked prior to the request being delegated to the controller, and both have access to the servlet.

Here is an [actual Logging example using a Spring Interceptor](http://www.vaannila.com/spring/spring-interceptor.html):

```
package com.vaannila.interceptor;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.handler. HandlerInterceptorAdapter;

public class LoggerInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LoggerInterceptor.class);

    static {
        BasicConfigurator.configure();
    }

    @Override

    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {

        logger.info("Before handling the request");
        return super.preHandle(request, response, handler);
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Object handler,
            ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {

        logger.info("After handling the request");
        super.postHandle(request, response, handler, modelAndView);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex)
            throws Exception {

        logger.info("After rendering the view");
        super.afterCompletion(request, response, handler, ex);
    }
}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.    InternalResourceViewResolver" p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp" />

    <bean id="handlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler. BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping" p:interceptors-ref="loggerInterceptor" />

    <bean id="loggerInterceptor" class="com.vaannila.interceptor.LoggerInterceptor" />

    <bean id="userService" class="com.vaannila.service.UserServiceImpl" />

    <bean name="/userRegistration.htm" class="com.vaannila.web.UserController" p:userService-ref="userService" p:formView="userForm" p:successView="userSuccess" />

</beans>
```

In the LoggerInterceptor, you could use the following code to access the request:

```
MyRequestWrapper myRequestWrapper = new MyRequestWrapper((HttpServletRequest) request);

String body = myRequestWrapper.getBody();
String clientIP = myRequestWrapper.getRemoteHost();
int clientPort = request.getRemotePort();
String uri = myRequestWrapper.getRequestURI();

System.out.println(body);
System.out.println(clientIP);
System.out.println(clientPort);
System.out.println(uri);
```

Comment: @user1323865 - Just noticed the unaccept. Does this no longer solve your problem? ;)

Comment: yep, I had done tests only with GET (stupid me). I have updated the question with more details. Could you please help?

Comment: You might need to post the DBLogInterceptor class, as well as the methods/class that is called by the POST, as well as the actual physical web request to the server (like the JavaScript code making the POST)

Comment: I'm assuming DBLoggerInterceptor is yours and not part of a library/framework ;)

Comment: I have already posted the DBLogInterceptor class. I have now updated the question with the method which is called while servicing the POST. Also, I use Apache HTTPClient for my tests, since UI is being done by someone else.

Comment: `12:04:53,821 DEBUG DBLogInterceptor:22 -`. That's in your log. I think it would help if we knew what was happening in there. If your code is removed, it's like trying to have my mechanic fix my car, but with the car locked in the garage and the keys hidden. Know what I mean ;)

Comment: Oops, I think I had not saved my edits earlier, now it's updated with service method. And Interceptor class, DBLogInterceptor is there in the update already. Please let me know if I must add anything else here.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11862/discussion-between-jmort253-and-user1323865)

Comment: FINALIZING: jmort253's answer work with one bit to change: replace spring interceptor with javax.servlet.Filter << wrap request there

Comment: Works perfectly fine using Spring's Interceptor for POST as well. Using Spring 4, Jackson 2.2

Comment: It cannot work, I am using Spring 4. Because the MyRequestWrapper is never used as user1323865 mentioned.

Comment: I am getting stream is closed exception , can anyone please help!

Comment: Please refer this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39921704/234110) for a cleaner access with Spring's `ContentCachingRequestWrapper` class.

Comment: `org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: I/O error while reading input message; nested exception is java.io.IOException: Stream closed`

Comment: did not work for me as well. Wrapped the request in a Filter, then accessed wrapped request in an interceptor, read the request body for a signature verification . But POST method in controller is still unable to parse @RequestBody. 'Request Body missing" error

Answer (score 6):

I doubt if `HttpServletRequestWrapper` can ever work... Take a look at the DispatcherServlet implementation:

```
            HandlerInterceptor[] interceptors = mappedHandler.getInterceptors();
            if (interceptors != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < interceptors.length; i++) {
                    HandlerInterceptor interceptor = interceptors[i];
                    if (!interceptor.preHandle(processedRequest, response, mappedHandler.getHandler())) {
                        triggerAfterCompletion(mappedHandler, interceptorIndex, processedRequest, response, null);
                        return;
                    }
                    interceptorIndex = i;
                }
            }

            // Actually invoke the handler.
            mv = ha.handle(processedRequest, response, mappedHandler.getHandler());
```

It passes reference to "`processedRequest`" still, which refers to a `HttpServletRequest` request whose stream has already been read.

Comment: Finally, I have to use filter instead. [like this](http://wetfeetblog.com/servlet-filer-to-log-request-and-response-details-and-payload/431)

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but for those of you that are still looking for a solution, this worked for me:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletInputStream;
import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.commons.io.output.TeeOutputStream;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class HttpLoggingFilter implements Filter {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HttpLoggingFilter.class);

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        try {
            HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
            HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;

            Map<String, String> requestMap = this
                    .getTypesafeRequestMap(httpServletRequest);
            BufferedRequestWrapper bufferedRequest = new BufferedRequestWrapper(
                    httpServletRequest);
            BufferedResponseWrapper bufferedResponse = new BufferedResponseWrapper(
                    httpServletResponse);

            final StringBuilder logMessage = new StringBuilder(
                    "REST Request - ").append("[HTTP METHOD:")
                    .append(httpServletRequest.getMethod())
                    .append("] [PATH INFO:")
                    .append(httpServletRequest.getPathInfo())
                    .append("] [REQUEST PARAMETERS:").append(requestMap)
                    .append("] [REQUEST BODY:")
                    .append(bufferedRequest.getRequestBody())
                    .append("] [REMOTE ADDRESS:")
                    .append(httpServletRequest.getRemoteAddr()).append("]");

            chain.doFilter(bufferedRequest, bufferedResponse);
            logMessage.append(" [RESPONSE:")
                    .append(bufferedResponse.getContent()).append("]");
            logger.debug(logMessage.toString());
        } catch (Throwable a) {
            logger.error(a.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private Map<String, String> getTypesafeRequestMap(HttpServletRequest request) {
        Map<String, String> typesafeRequestMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Enumeration<?> requestParamNames = request.getParameterNames();
        while (requestParamNames.hasMoreElements()) {
            String requestParamName = (String) requestParamNames.nextElement();
            String requestParamValue = request.getParameter(requestParamName);
            typesafeRequestMap.put(requestParamName, requestParamValue);
        }
        return typesafeRequestMap;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

    private static final class BufferedRequestWrapper extends
            HttpServletRequestWrapper {

        private ByteArrayInputStream bais = null;
        private ByteArrayOutputStream baos = null;
        private BufferedServletInputStream bsis = null;
        private byte[] buffer = null;

        public BufferedRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest req)
                throws IOException {
            super(req);
            // Read InputStream and store its content in a buffer.
            InputStream is = req.getInputStream();
            this.baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
            int read;
            while ((read = is.read(buf)) > 0) {
                this.baos.write(buf, 0, read);
            }
            this.buffer = this.baos.toByteArray();
        }

        @Override
        public ServletInputStream getInputStream() {
            this.bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(this.buffer);
            this.bsis = new BufferedServletInputStream(this.bais);
            return this.bsis;
        }

        String getRequestBody() throws IOException {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    this.getInputStream()));
            String line = null;
            StringBuilder inputBuffer = new StringBuilder();
            do {
                line = reader.readLine();
                if (null != line) {
                    inputBuffer.append(line.trim());
                }
            } while (line != null);
            reader.close();
            return inputBuffer.toString().trim();
        }

    }

    private static final class BufferedServletInputStream extends
            ServletInputStream {

        private ByteArrayInputStream bais;

        public BufferedServletInputStream(ByteArrayInputStream bais) {
            this.bais = bais;
        }

        @Override
        public int available() {
            return this.bais.available();
        }

        @Override
        public int read() {
            return this.bais.read();
        }

        @Override
        public int read(byte[] buf, int off, int len) {
            return this.bais.read(buf, off, len);
        }

    }

    public class TeeServletOutputStream extends ServletOutputStream {

        private final TeeOutputStream targetStream;

        public TeeServletOutputStream(OutputStream one, OutputStream two) {
            targetStream = new TeeOutputStream(one, two);
        }

        @Override
        public void write(int arg0) throws IOException {
            this.targetStream.write(arg0);
        }

        public void flush() throws IOException {
            super.flush();
            this.targetStream.flush();
        }

        public void close() throws IOException {
            super.close();
            this.targetStream.close();
        }
    }

    public class BufferedResponseWrapper implements HttpServletResponse {

        HttpServletResponse original;
        TeeServletOutputStream tee;
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos;

        public BufferedResponseWrapper(HttpServletResponse response) {
            original = response;
        }

        public String getContent() {
            return bos.toString();
        }

        public PrintWriter getWriter() throws IOException {
            return original.getWriter();
        }

        public ServletOutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
            if (tee == null) {
                bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                tee = new TeeServletOutputStream(original.getOutputStream(),
                        bos);
            }
            return tee;

        }

        @Override
        public String getCharacterEncoding() {
            return original.getCharacterEncoding();
        }

        @Override
        public String getContentType() {
            return original.getContentType();
        }

        @Override
        public void setCharacterEncoding(String charset) {
            original.setCharacterEncoding(charset);
        }

        @Override
        public void setContentLength(int len) {
            original.setContentLength(len);
        }

        @Override
        public void setContentType(String type) {
            original.setContentType(type);
        }

        @Override
        public void setBufferSize(int size) {
            original.setBufferSize(size);
        }

        @Override
        public int getBufferSize() {
            return original.getBufferSize();
        }

        @Override
        public void flushBuffer() throws IOException {
            tee.flush();
        }

        @Override
        public void resetBuffer() {
            original.resetBuffer();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCommitted() {
            return original.isCommitted();
        }

        @Override
        public void reset() {
            original.reset();
        }

        @Override
        public void setLocale(Locale loc) {
            original.setLocale(loc);
        }

        @Override
        public Locale getLocale() {
            return original.getLocale();
        }

        @Override
        public void addCookie(Cookie cookie) {
            original.addCookie(cookie);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean containsHeader(String name) {
            return original.containsHeader(name);
        }

        @Override
        public String encodeURL(String url) {
            return original.encodeURL(url);
        }

        @Override
        public String encodeRedirectURL(String url) {
            return original.encodeRedirectURL(url);
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public String encodeUrl(String url) {
            return original.encodeUrl(url);
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public String encodeRedirectUrl(String url) {
            return original.encodeRedirectUrl(url);
        }

        @Override
        public void sendError(int sc, String msg) throws IOException {
            original.sendError(sc, msg);
        }

        @Override
        public void sendError(int sc) throws IOException {
            original.sendError(sc);
        }

        @Override
        public void sendRedirect(String location) throws IOException {
            original.sendRedirect(location);
        }

        @Override
        public void setDateHeader(String name, long date) {
            original.setDateHeader(name, date);
        }

        @Override
        public void addDateHeader(String name, long date) {
            original.addDateHeader(name, date);
        }

        @Override
        public void setHeader(String name, String value) {
            original.setHeader(name, value);
        }

        @Override
        public void addHeader(String name, String value) {
            original.addHeader(name, value);
        }

        @Override
        public void setIntHeader(String name, int value) {
            original.setIntHeader(name, value);
        }

        @Override
        public void addIntHeader(String name, int value) {
            original.addIntHeader(name, value);
        }

        @Override
        public void setStatus(int sc) {
            original.setStatus(sc);
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void setStatus(int sc, String sm) {
            original.setStatus(sc, sm);
        }

        @Override
        public String getHeader(String arg0) {
            return original.getHeader(arg0);
        }

        @Override
        public Collection<String> getHeaderNames() {
            return original.getHeaderNames();
        }

        @Override
        public Collection<String> getHeaders(String arg0) {
            return original.getHeaders(arg0);
        }

        @Override
        public int getStatus() {
            return original.getStatus();
        }

    }
}
```

Then simply register the filter in web.xml and you're done. All credits to: http://wetfeetblog.com/servlet-filer-to-log-request-and-response-details-and-payload/431 (I just did some minor fix to it).

Answer (score 3):

Hey can you try with this:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/json", produces="application/json", value = "/employee")
@ResponseBody
public String updateEntity(@RequestBody Employee emp) {
    // Do some DB Stuff. Anyway, the control flow does not reach this place.
    return "Employee " + emp.getName() + " updated successfully!";
}
```

Here: it you proving URI with the '/' it allows all the operations to perform. such as get post update and delete with same URI value.

Answer (score 2):

Currently in spring-mvc repo, interceptors are invoked in DispatcherServlet#doDispatch(...):

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.java

```
...
        if (!mappedHandler.applyPreHandle(processedRequest, response)) {
            return;
        }

        try {
            // Actually invoke the handler.
            mv = ha.handle(processedRequest, response, mappedHandler.getHandler());
        }
        finally {
            if (asyncManager.isConcurrentHandlingStarted()) {
                return;
            }
        }

        applyDefaultViewName(request, mv);
        mappedHandler.applyPostHandle(processedRequest, response, mv);
...
```

Can I define my own `DispatcherServlet`, and override `doDispatch(...)` to inject a `HttpRequestWrapper` with a `ByteArrayInputStream` on `getInputStream()`?

```
...

@Override
    protected void doDispatch(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {

        RequestWrapper wrappedRequest = new RequestWrapper(request);
        logger.debug("injecting RequestWrapper: " + wrappedRequest);

        super.doDispatch(wrappedRequest, response);

    }
...
```

Will this work for the above situation?

Answer (score 2):

I make a Ouputstream version without any dependency to 3rd party libs for easier re-use. You can use this 2 wrapper class to get the request & response body easily.

But anyway, I have to use a filter to do this instead of interceptor. Because as @user1323865 mentioned, in spring 4, the processedRequest is used in both interceptor and handler, so you cannot use these methods for interceptor.

Also you can find some help in this link if you're using Writer version instead.
[Capture and log the response body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242236/capture-and-log-the-response-body)

```
public class BufferedRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper
{
    private static final class BufferedServletInputStream extends ServletInputStream
    {
        private ByteArrayInputStream bais;

        public BufferedServletInputStream(ByteArrayInputStream bais)
        {
            this.bais = bais;
        }

        @Override
        public int available()
        {
            return this.bais.available();
        }

        @Override
        public int read()
        {
            return this.bais.read();
        }

        @Override
        public int read(byte[] buf, int off, int len)
        {
            return this.bais.read(buf, off, len);
        }

    }

    private byte[] mBodyBuffer;

    public BufferedRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException
    {
        super(request);

        InputStream in = request.getInputStream();

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead = -1;
        while ((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
        {
            baos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        mBodyBuffer = baos.toByteArray();
    }

    public String getRequestBody()
    {
        return new String(mBodyBuffer, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    }
    @Override
    public BufferedReader getReader() throws IOException
    {
        return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.getInputStream()));
    }

    @Override
    public ServletInputStream getInputStream()
    {
        ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(mBodyBuffer);
        return new BufferedServletInputStream(in);
    }
}


public class BufferedResponseWrapper extends HttpServletResponseWrapper
{
    private TeeServletOutputStream mTeeOutputStream;

    private static class TeeOutputStream extends OutputStream
    {
        private OutputStream mChainStream;
        private OutputStream mTeeStream;

        public TeeOutputStream(OutputStream chainStream, OutputStream teeStream)
        {
            mChainStream = chainStream;
            mTeeStream = teeStream;
        }

        @Override
        public void write(int b) throws IOException
        {
            mChainStream.write(b);
            mTeeStream.write(b);
            mTeeStream.flush();
        }

        @Override
        public void close() throws IOException
        {
            flush();
            mChainStream.close();
            mTeeStream.close();
        }

        @Override
        public void flush() throws IOException
        {
            mChainStream.close();
        }
    }

    public class TeeServletOutputStream extends ServletOutputStream
    {
        private final TeeOutputStream targetStream;

        public TeeServletOutputStream(OutputStream one, OutputStream two)
        {
            targetStream = new TeeOutputStream(one, two);
        }

        @Override
        public void write(int b) throws IOException
        {
            this.targetStream.write(b);
        }

        @Override
        public void flush() throws IOException
        {
            super.flush();
            this.targetStream.flush();
        }

        @Override
        public void close() throws IOException
        {
            super.close();
            this.targetStream.close();
        }
    }

    private ByteArrayOutputStream mByteArrayOutputStream;

    public BufferedResponseWrapper(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException
    {
        super(response);
        mByteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        mTeeOutputStream = new TeeServletOutputStream(super.getResponse().getOutputStream(), mByteArrayOutputStream);
    }

    @Override
    public PrintWriter getWriter() throws IOException
    {
        return super.getResponse().getWriter();
    }

    @Override
    public ServletOutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException
    {
        return mTeeOutputStream;
    }

    public String getResponseBody()
    {
        return mByteArrayOutputStream.toString();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

One simple way to do this would be to get the request body as String and then parse as a Java object. You can use this String then as you want.

So in your example:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/json", produces="application/json", value = "employee")
@ResponseBody
public String updateEntity(@RequestBody String empAsString) {

    // Do whatever with the json as String 
    System.out.println(empAsString);

    // Transform it into the Java Object you want
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Employee emp = mapper.readValue(empAsString, Employee.class);

    // Do some DB Stuff. Anyway, the control flow does not reach this place.
    return "Employee " + emp.getName() + " updated successfully!";
}
```

As a note, if you need it as a list you can use:

```
List<Employee> eventsList =
                mapper.readValue(jsonInString, mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, Employee.class));
```

Comment: I was going through all of these trying to find something (that worked) without touching the code. Sometimes, changing 4-5 lines of code is the answer. Addtionally, coupled with `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` this somewhat future-proofed my class when the next external API change occurs.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the requestWrapper as follows:

```
public class DocVerificationRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {
 private final String body;
 public DocVerificationRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
   super(request);
   StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
   BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
   try {
     InputStream inputStream = request.getInputStream();
     if (inputStream != null) {
       bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
       char[] charBuffer = new char[128];
       int bytesRead = -1;
       while ((bytesRead = bufferedReader.read(charBuffer)) > 0) {
         stringBuilder.append(charBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
       }
     } else {
       stringBuilder.append("");
     }
   } catch (IOException ex) {
       throw ex;
   } finally {
     if (bufferedReader != null) {
       try {
         bufferedReader.close();
       } catch (IOException ex) {
         throw ex;
       }
     }
   }
   body = stringBuilder.toString();
 }

 @Override
 public ServletInputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
   final ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new     ByteArrayInputStream(body.getBytes());
   ServletInputStream servletInputStream = new ServletInputStream() {
     public int read() throws IOException {
       return byteArrayInputStream.read();
     }

    @Override
    public boolean isFinished() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isReady() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void setReadListener(ReadListener listener) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
   };
   return servletInputStream;
 }

 @Override
 public BufferedReader getReader() throws IOException {
   return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.getInputStream()));
 }

 public String getBody() {
   return this.body;
 }
}
```

and then inside the chain.doFilter method of filter class pass the requestWrapper object instead of the request object as follows:

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest arg0, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

    logger.info("checking token in filter");
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) arg0;

    DocVerificationRequestWrapper myRequestWrapper = new DocVerificationRequestWrapper((HttpServletRequest) request);

    String body = myRequestWrapper.getBody();
    logger.info("body = "+body);
    Token token = null;
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(body);
        JSONObject tokenObj = (JSONObject) jsonObj.get("token");
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        token = gson.fromJson(tokenObj.toString(), Token.class);

        if(null != token) {
                if(userVerificationService==null){
                ServletContext servletContext = request.getServletContext();
                WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(servletContext);
                userVerificationService = webApplicationContext.getBean(UserVerificationService.class);
            }
                String verStatus = userVerificationService.verifyUser(token);
                logger.info("verStatus = "+verStatus);
                if(verStatus != null && verStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {
                    chain.doFilter(myRequestWrapper, response); //here replacing request with requestWrapper 
                }else
                    logger.error("Invalid token");
        }else {
                logger.error("token missing.");
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
            logger.error("exception in authetication filter " + e);
    }
}
```

Thus solving the IOStream closed exception.

Answer (score 0):

For getting data from Body you can try to read and recreate InputStream in RequestBodyAdviceAdapter:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomRequestBodyAdviceAdapter extends RequestBodyAdviceAdapter {

    @Override
    public HttpInputMessage beforeBodyRead(HttpInputMessage inputMessage, MethodParameter parameter, Type targetType, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType) throws IOException {
        String body = IOUtils.toString(inputMessage.getBody(), UTF_8.name());

        HttpInputMessage myMessage = new HttpInputMessage(){
            @Override
            public InputStream getBody() throws IOException {
                return new ByteArrayInputStream(body.getBytes());
            }
            @Override
            public HttpHeaders getHeaders() {
                return inputMessage.getHeaders();
            }
        };

        System.out.println("Data from Body: " + body);

        return super.beforeBodyRead(myMessage, parameter, targetType, converterType);
    }

    @Override
    public Object handleEmptyBody(Object body, HttpInputMessage inputMessage, MethodParameter parameter, Type targetType, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType) {
        System.out.println("Data from Body is empty");
        return super.handleEmptyBody(body, inputMessage, parameter, targetType, converterType);
    }

    @Override
    public Object afterBodyRead(Object body, HttpInputMessage inputMessage, MethodParameter parameter, Type targetType, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType) {
        return super.afterBodyRead(body, inputMessage, parameter, targetType, converterType);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(MethodParameter methodParameter, Type targetType, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use :

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

String requestBody = IOUtils.toString(request.getInputStream(), Charset.forName("UTF-8").toString());
```

Answer (score -3):

In my experiences,just develop as follows:
Using the filter in order to wrapper ServletRequest,then you can repeatly use getting request input stream.