# How can I modify JSON object sent in request body from UI side before reaching to spring controller?

Tags: spring

How can I modify JSON object sent in request body from UI side before reaching to spring controller?

I tried adding filter , but as soon as I read from request(servletrequest.getReader()) and then forward request to next filter in filter chain it fails(Request doesnt reach to controller).

```
BufferedReader reader = servletrequest.getReader();
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
buffer.append(line);
String data = buffer.toString();
```

Using this I got JSON in string but I am not able to figure out how to put it back in request.

Comment: Add your code where you got problem.. post stack-trace if you got any error.

Comment: I tried the above code to get JSON in string. But I am not able to put modified JSON in request and continue with filter chain

Comment: from client how will you send JSON to server ? is there any JavaScript function or any other thing ?

Comment: yes simple ajax post request with "data: JSON.stringify(XYZ)".

Comment: Are you trying to modify the JSON for a single controller or all? Why?

Comment: You can only read the request once, when it is read the content isn't available anymore. Why do you need to modify the JSON seems like a hack to me.

Comment: @chrylis I want to do it only for 1 request

Comment: @M.Deinum I am sending encrypted value from UI and before it reaches to controller I want to decrypt it

Comment: is it need to alter no server side only? you can change it on client side if this is not required.

Comment: @JavaDev Yes I need to do it on server side just before controller

Answer (score 1):

using [HandlerInterceptor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html) by Spring.You can also specifically choose to intercept specific requests. check [this tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-handler-interceptors-example/) .This is all dependent on the version of Spring you are using.But this should give you a fair outlook into how to go about it.

```
package com.test.intercept;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerInterceptorAdapter;



public class HttpRequestInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {


@Autowired
private ServletContext context;

@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
    HandlerMethod handlerMethod = (HandlerMethod) handler;
    String methodName = handlerMethod.getMethod().getName();
    Map<String, String> headerMap = HttpUtil.getAllHeaders(request);
    Boolean isAllowed=false;

    //doing what you want to your json
    //
    return isAllowed;
}

@Override
public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest arg0,
        HttpServletResponse arg1, Object arg2, Exception arg3)
        throws Exception {
    logger.info("in after completion");

}

@Override
public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest arg0, HttpServletResponse arg1,
        Object arg2, ModelAndView arg3) throws Exception {
    logger.info("in posthandle");

}
```

and in your servletContext.xml add :

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/api/**" /> <!--to exclude a path -->
        <mvc:exclude-mapping path="/web/**" /> <!--to exclude a path -->
        <beans:bean class="com.test.interceptor.HttpRequestInterceptor"></beans:bean>
    </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

Comment: I am able to get request parameter before reaching to controller in one of my filter(although this is better approach) but I want to know how can I get JSON from request and modify it.

Comment: see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10458119/3396197)  where it states that request body can be read only once.So I dont think modifying the JSON would be useful for you since you cannot access it in the next step.

Comment: If it absolutely necessary to pass data the way you want,you can modify headers ininterceptors.Maybe you could use that instead

Comment: what is HttpUtil.getAllHeaders(request);?