# Get request body as string/json to validate with a json schema- Spring boot REST API

Tags: spring-boot, httprequest, json-schema-validator

I'm trying to validate JSON (passed by a client as a request body) before it is converted into a model in Controller method.

If validation passes then return nothing, let the process continue as it was (spring boot to convert JSON into a model marked as @RequestBody). Throw error in case validation fails ([everit-org/json-schema](https://github.com/everit-org/json-schema)).

I tried to two way:

1. Implement `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`, but `resolveArgument()` doesn't give request body details as it is already read and stored in `ContentCachingRequestWrapper`.

   NOTE: `inputStream` in `ContentCachingRequestWrapper` doesn't have any request body details.
2. Using [spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10457963/spring-rest-service-retrieving-json-from-request/29005111) `Interceptor`. But this doesn't help me to find request body type passed in the request. As JSON schema is different for each request.

Any other approaches I can try with?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot add a comment ... so ...

What kind of validation do you need? If you only want to validate the fields like length of a string or range of a number and so on. I recommend you use `@Validated` on controller mehtod parameter, and model:

```
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 32, max = 32)
    private String id;
```

controller:

```
@PatchMapping
public Object update(@RequestBody @Validated User user, Errors errors) {
    ...
}
```

If there is something wrong, `errors.hasErrors()` will return `true`.

edit:

OK, I did some tests, in a filter :

```
    HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest)request;
    ServletInputStream inputStream = httpServletRequest.getInputStream();
    byte[] a = new byte[1024];
    inputStream.read(a);
    System.out.println(IOUtils.toString(a));
```

I got a json string (a piece of request body) :

```
    {"template":"5AF78355A4F0D58E03CE9F55AFA850F8","bd":"" ...
```

Comment: I hav JSON schema. Would like to validate request JSON against it.Dont need @Validate approach..Thanks..

Comment: Yes.There are some suggestions to use filters. I remember it vaguely,not sure if I tried it or not. Please update in case filters worked for you.

Comment: Would be  great if you could share a working sample project in GitHub.As I could see many others seeking for a solution.

Comment: ... it's company's project, there are not much things that related with these code ...