# How to pass a comma separated list in jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a jsp/html form that collects an array of choices from user. For example, I ask "what did you like about this food?" and the user can add 1 answer per input field (with option to put in unlimited number of choices).
Here is what the html looks like:

```
<li><input type="text" name="choiceList[]" /></li>
<li><input type="text" name="choiceList[]" /></li>
<li><input type="text" name="choiceList[]" /></li>
<li><input type="text" name="choiceList[]" /></li>
<li><input type="text" name="choiceList[]" /></li>
```

...

In my backend (which is using Spring) I assign the choiceList array to a `String[] choices` java array.

My problem with this is that if somebody puts a comma separated list in one of the input fields (for example: apple, mango, orange") and "pineapple" in another input field, the backed java array thinks the user input was 4 separate items (apple, mango, orange, pineapple) because the html form array `choiceList[]` is basically a comma separated list.

What do I need to do in my form so I can really tell that the user filled out only 2 input fields? To be clearer, I want my java array to be of size 2 not of size 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I basically had the same issue a while back and asked this question SO: [How to prevent parameter binding from interpreting commas in Spring 3.0.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998748/how-to-prevent-parameter-binding-from-interpreting-commas-in-spring-3-0-5)?

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5239841/249327) will allow you to prevent Spring interpretting the commas in the users' input.

Comment: thanks. That does the trick.I still find it strange that what looks like a simple issue takes that much modification to get it working properly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [@InitBinder annotation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/mvc.html#mvc-ann-initbinder) to configure binding for string array:

```
@InitBinder("choiceList")
public void fqBinderInit(WebDataBinder b) {
  b.registerCustomEditor(String[].class, new StringArrayPropertyEditor("&"));
}
```

Comment: I read the Spring doc. and wrote this method in my form controller:
@InitBinder("choiceNames")
 public void initBinder(WebDataBinder b) {
  b.registerCustomEditor(String.class, new StringArrayPropertyEditor("&"));
 }
Is that all I need to do? I put it in my application and I did not notice anything different.

Comment: Just to be clearer, if a user enters "apple, orange, mango" in one input field only, there is no "&" sent to the backend.

Answer (score 1):

@Stealth - since my answer is little big i added a new answer.
If you have dynamic input's being added in the form, then i can think of one solution is have the complete input list as a json string and send the complete json string in the request to the server. For example you can have the names of the input in your own convention, as you currently have "choiceList", you can have the inputs as "choiceList1", "choiceList2" etc, you can maintain the existing counts and when you are creating new texts you can increment the counter and form the new name. For example on load of form you have 2 fields then the counter is 2, when creating a new field using js then the counter becomes 3 and the text field name will be "choiceList3". Now before submit you should call a javascript method which iterates all the input fields and form the json string as `[{"choiceList1": "apple, mango, orages", "choiceList2": "pear", "choiceList3": "strawberry"}]`. This whole string can be submitted to the backend and you can use process it in the backend.

Answer (score 0):

If the names of the input type is same, in your case its "choiceList" so ideally the http request does by appending the both the input with comma seperated. Ideally you should have 10 different text fields with different names for example choice1, choice2 etc and get whatever input they are entering and process accordingly in the backend. This is my thought.

Comment: I also thought about that, but my page will eventually allow unlimited number of input fields (using js. I have also updated my question to reflect that). So this solution would not work in the future.