# Binding multiple select where option values may contain commas in Spring 3

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, binding, multi-select

We are having an issue with binding a multiple select element when the option values contain commas. We have tried binding to both a `String` and to a `List<String>`, but have issues with both.

When a multiple select element is posted, the value of each selected option is passed in a separate request parameter, all with the same name. For example, if the select element name is "code", the parameters might look like this:

```
code=ABC
code=A,B
code=XYZ
```

When binding to a `String`, Spring will automatically join these values into a comma-separated string. That is obviously an issue if one or more of the values contains a comma.

When binding to a `List<String>`, things work fine when multiple options are selected. In that case, Spring creates a `List` with an entry for each selected option. But if only one option is selected, Spring assumes the value is a comma-separated list and will split it into multiple entries.

Is there a way to tell Spring to use a different character than a comma when binding to a `String`? Is there a way to tell Spring not to split a single value when binding to a `List<String>`? Or is there another way to deal with this?

Comment: I believe this thread is related to your issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998748/how-to-prevent-parameter-binding-from-interpreting-commas-in-spring-3-0-5. This Spring issue may also be helpful: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-7963

Comment: @vincentks - Thank you for those links. They are definitely related. I always included "multiple select" in my searches. That's probably why I didn't find those.

Comment: @vincentks Why you didn't put that into an actual answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this thread is related to your issue: [How to prevent parameter binding from interpreting commas in Spring 3.0.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998748/how-to-prevent-parameter-binding-from-interpreting-commas-in-spring-3-0-5). This Spring issue may also be helpful: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-7963

The solution provided at https://stackoverflow.com/a/5239841/1259928, which details how to create a new conversion service which uses a different string separator and wiring it into Spring config should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks again. These links did provide the answer.