# Array value not populated correctly in form:select tag

Tags: java, arrays, spring, spring-mvc

```
 <c:forEach items="${bean.items}" var="element" >
    <c:set var="optionString" value="${element.optionString}"/>
    <%String s = (String)pageContext.getAttribute("optionString");%>
    <form:option  value="<%=s%>">Option Name to be displayed</form:option>
</c:forEach>
```

In the above code ${bean.items} is a array of strings. and ${element.optionString} give String value "0000,1234,2345,3456"

My Expectation is the if the above value is selected the select tags path variable "selectedItems" which is also an array should be populated with one value "0000,1234,2345,3456" but instead "selectedItems" is having array of four elements with "0000" , "1234" , "2345" , "3456". Now array sizre is four.

What am i doing wrong here?  Why the value is not populated as single element in the Array?

Answer (score 0):

What you're facing is a default for Spring MVC. That is beacuse the delimiter the Spring MVC uses when converting String to String[] is in fact comma. Check the accepted answer here, to learn how to change it

[How to prevent parameter binding from interpreting commas in Spring 3.0.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998748/how-to-prevent-parameter-binding-from-interpreting-commas-in-spring-3-0-5)

Comment: Thanks.., Interestingly when I have two values in the option tag as <form:option value="0000,01234,02345,0456"/><form:option value = "1234,2334,3445,2346" />. Now my path variable is updated with array of two elements(0000,01234,02345,0456 , 1234,2334,3445,2346) . In this case it doesn't seem like it is entirely using comma as separator else I would have 12 elements in array but i have only 2. Any Ideas on this?

Comment: that is interesting, how exactly the path variable looks like in the request? Anyways, to de-mistify anything that confuses you there, you can simply debug through StringToArrayConverter and see what changes in the two cases

Comment: In request the path variable is String[1] only but when binding to command variable it is String[6]