# Spring framework does not map list request parameter correctly

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a web request like

```
/path?param=value1&param=value2
```

which maps to a `List<String>` param on the Controller side.

The important aspect to note is that value1 and value2 can have a comma(,) in their values.

I see 2 different behaviors with spring request parameter mapping.

Case 1. `/path?param=part1%2Cpart2 (url encoded comma)`

Spring request parameter maps this to a List of size 2 with part1 and part2 as the elements, but `HttpServletRequest.getParameterValues("param")` is correctly assigned to an array of size 1 with value=part1,part2

Case 2. `/path?param=part1%2Cpart2&param=part3%2Cpart4`

In this case Spring correctly maps this to a list of 2 values, and so does the HttpServletRequest parameter.

I guess Spring is supporting mapping `List` parameter with both csv values and repeating the parameter. Is there a way to tell Spring to use a particular mapping method?

I'm using spring-mvc 3.2.13

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/mymethod", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody Boolean method(MyRequest myReq, HttpServletRequest request) {

    }

 }

 public class MyRequest {
    List<String> param;
 }
```

Comment: From SpringMVC 3 experience, I've never seen `@Controller` handle multiple keys in GET params. Post your `@Controller` code, then we have more information to work from.

Comment: added the controller code.

Comment: Some solutions are here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998748/how-to-prevent-parameter-binding-from-interpreting-commas-in-spring-3-0-5

Answer (score 1):

I've actually never seen this before, but have done a bit of reading and the recommended way to do it for POST seems to be to pass the values as follow:

```
/path?param=value1&param=value2&param=value3
```

And then in the `@Controller`, have a `@RequestParam` which contains a value of `param[]` - note the square brackets.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/path", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void doSomething(@RequestParam(value = "param[]") String[] paramValues){...}
```

I haven't tested `POST`, but I have tested `GET` and I got it working using:

```
/path?code=1&height=300&width=300&param=3&param=5&param=7
```

And then in my `@Controller`

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/path", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void blah(
        HttpServletResponse response,
        @RequestParam("code") String code,
        @RequestParam("width") Integer width,
        @RequestParam("height") Integer height,
        @RequestParam(value = "param") String[] params) {

        for (int i = 0; i < params.length; i++){
            System.out.println(params[i]);
        }
```

And this printed

```
3
5
7
```

Comment: The main issue is that my values contain comma. Can you try replacing param=3 with param=test,value?

Comment: This is the closest you'll come to getting lists from SpringMVC as far as I've read yesterday, if you want to make it work, you'll need to send it in the format `param=test&param=value` or alternatively manually split it using `String[] subparams = param.split(",");`

Comment: Think you misunderstood. "test,value" is 1 parameter, but spring splits it into 2. See the 2 cases above in the question.

Comment: I'm also looking for answer to this problem. when you pass just one param with "test,value" like `?param=test,value` it gives you 2 values, instead it should give 1 value