# Spring boot converter API is not converting the sort object as expected

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have created a webservice using spring boot. I am using below URL to sort all projects retrieved from the database (sort by projectId attribute, sort direction is descending)

```
http://localhost:8081/api/projects?sort=projectId,desc
```

In my controller getAllProjects  method looks something like below

```
@GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Page<Project>> getAllProjects(
            @Valid ProjectPage projectPage,
            ProjectSearchCriteria projectSearchCriteria){
        return null;
    }
```

My ProjectPage model can accept multiple sort query parameters as well

```
public class ProjectPage {    
    @Valid
    private List<PageSort> sort;
}
```

and my PageSort model is as below

```
public class PageSort {
    private String sortBy;
    private String sortDirection;
}
```

In order to convert the java.lang.String (projectId,desc passed in the request URL) to PageSort I have used converter SPI documented in https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#core-convert-Converter-API and this works perfectly.

According to the steps in the documentation;

Step 1: I have extended the WebMvcConfigurationSupport

```
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
    @Override
    protected void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        registry.addConverter(stringToPageSortConverter());
        super.addFormatters(registry);
    }

    @Bean
    public StringToPageSortConverter stringToPageSortConverter(){
        return new StringToPageSortConverter();
    }
}
```

Step 2: And implemented the Converter as below

```
@Component
public class StringToPageSortConverter implements Converter<String, PageSort> {
    @Override
    public PageSort convert(String source) {
        PageSort pageSort;
        String[] _sort = source.split(",");
        if(_sort.length > 1){
            pageSort = PageSort.builder()
                    .sortBy(_sort[0])
                    .sortDirection(_sort[1])
                    .build();
        }else{
            pageSort = PageSort.builder()
                    .sortBy(_sort[0])
                    .sortDirection("asc")
                    .build();
        }

        return pageSort;
    }
}
```

When I invoke http://localhost:8081/api/projects?sort=projectId,desc and check the StringToPageSortConvertervariable class I am seeing something as below. (Attaching snippets of the output as it's easier to see the issue graphically)

1). snippet one is ok as it's expected

[image]

2). But when I continue resume from the breakpoint it hits the breakpoint again which is ideally wrong.

[image]

In the final projectPage variable in the controller now have two sort objects. (0th element is correct and the 1st is not correct and it should not be added there at all)

[image]

I am not sure whether I am missing something here.

Any input from the community is much appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding below code in the controller fixed the issue

```
@InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.registerCustomEditor(List.class, new CustomCollectionEditor(List.class));
    }
```

Got the help from below stackoverflow question
[How to prevent Spring MVC from interpreting commas when converting to a Collection in Spring Boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42120588/how-to-prevent-spring-mvc-from-interpreting-commas-when-converting-to-a-collecti)

Answer (score 0):

Try using this @PathVariable("sort") in your controller:

```java
@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<Page<Project>> getAllProjects( @Valid @PathVariable("sort") ProjectPage projectPage, ProjectSearchCriteria projectSearchCriteria){
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Didn't work. I think it is more to that