# Spring ModelAttribute correct parsing

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, modelattribute

I have Spring controller with endpoint like:

```
@RequestMapping("/provider")
public ResponseEntity<Something> load(@ModelAttribute PageRequest pageRequest)
{
    ... //do something
}
```

where `PageRequest` is simple POJO:

```
class PageRequest 
{
    String[] field;
    String[] value;
    ... // constructor getters settest
}
```

When I GET request like:
`.../provider?field=commanders&value=John%2CBill%2CAlex` then `pageRequest`data is mapped:

```
field[0] = commanders;

value[0] = John
value[1] = Bill
value[2] = Alex
```

But when I GET request like:
`.../provider?field=country&value=Australia&field=commanders&value=John%2CBill%2CAlex` then `pageRequest`data is mapped:

```
field[0] = country;
field[1] = commanders;

value[0] = Australia
value[1] = "John,Bill,Alex"
```

My question is why mapping is different for these requests, and can it be done for first request same as for the second. (comma `%2C` separated data map to single value).

`used: Spring 3.x`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some investigation and figured out that for first request `value=John%2CBill%2CAlex` Spring using `org.springframework.format.supportDefaultFormattingConversionService` class which under the hood has `org.springframework.core.convert.support.StringToArrayConverter` whose `convert()` method split your string by to array using comma as a separator.

You have 2 ways to resolve this issue:

1. Use ; instead of , as separator for you value (`value=John;Bill;Alex`)
2. Use different conversion service bean containing your own converter from String to String[]. For more details look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998748/how-to-prevent-parameter-binding-from-interpreting-commas-in-spring-3-0-5)