# Spring-boot filter handling with query params

Tags: java, spring-boot, query-string

In a REST endpoint, I want to receive filters as query parameters. Each filter is defined in a key-value pair separated by commas as follows:

`www.example.com/things?filter=key:value,key2:value2,key3:value3`

This example means that the list of Things I'm trying to get must have the `key` as `value`, **and** the `key2` as `value2` **and** `key3` as `value3`

In this endpoint I can receive multiple filters, like this:

`www.example.com/things?filter=key:value&filter=key2:value2,key3:value3`

This means that the list of things must have `key` as `value` **or** (`key2` as `value2` and `key3` as `value3`)

In spring-boot, the way to receive multiple query parameters that have the same name is by defining in your controller a `@RequestParam("filter") String[] filters`. But here's the issue: whenever I'll send just a single `filter` query parameter, I'll get an array of Strings formed by each key-pair value. If I send multiple `filter`, I'll get an array with each filter (as expected).

This means that for the first example, I will have an array of size 3 for each key pair, while in the second example I would receive an array of Size 2.

I need that, whenever I send just a single `filter` as query param, the `@RequestParam` tag delivers an array of size 1 with the whole String to be parsed later. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There might be better ways to achieve what you're after, but this is my suggestion.

A quick proof of concept, using `Spring Boot 2.2.1.RELEASE`, printing every filter on a separate line

```
import org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/things")
public class ThingController {

    @GetMapping
    public void filters(@RequestParam MultiValueMap<String, String> filters) {
        System.out.println("Filters:");
        filters.get("filter").forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

---

A curl command using only a single `filter` query param:

```
curl -v 'http://localhost:8080/things/?filter=key:value,key2:value2,key3:value3'
```

Prints:

```
Filters:
key:value,key2:value2,key3:value3
```

---

A curl command using only multiple `filter` query params:

```
curl -v 'http://localhost:8080/things/?filter=key:value&filter=key2:value2,key3:value3'
```

Prints:

```
Filters:
key:value
key2:value2,key3:value3
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need. But literally I've copied and pasted the code and I get a `Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap'`. Maybe an import I'm missing?

Comment: Added imports to `ThingController` example. Also included Spring Boot version (also tested using `Spring Boot 2.1.6.RELEASE`). Did you copy `ThingController` verbatim, and also try using the provided `curl` commands?

Comment: Issue was that I changed the pasted code to be `@RequestParam("filter")` which somehow made it fail. When I left it blank, as your example states, it worked.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to achieve is actually the default behaviour. If you declare an array in @RequestParam you will have the query parameters in the array no matter the number of parameters you send.

**EDIT:**
For example, given this controller:

```
@GetMapping("/things")
public ResponseEntity getThings(@RequestParam("filter") String[] filters) {

    return ResponseEntity.ok(filters);
}
```

You can call it in two different ways:

- www.example.com/things?filter=key:value,key2:value2,key3:value3
- www.example.com/things?filter=key:value&filter=key2:value2&filter=key3:value3

Both of them map to the same array:

```
[
 "key:value",
 "key2:value2",
 "key3:value3"
]
```

**EDIT2:** I just checked that you can't mix the two ways. If you do so, the comma separated items will be in the same array item. Maybe that was happening to you

Comment: What I want is that the comma separated items be all in a single position in the array, for each `filter` query param I define.

Comment: Now I fully understand you question. Then I'm afraid you need to implement your own converter, check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998748/how-to-prevent-parameter-binding-from-interpreting-commas-in-spring-3-0-5